# Excel VBA Function to count number of records per month

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following excel format and need to find out the number of records per Cust (Title1) per month (Title2):

```
Title1  Title2
CustA   1/1/2017
CustA   1/1/2017
CustB   1/1/2017
CustC   2/2/2017
CustD   2/2/2017
CustE   3/3/2017
```

Basically, the result needs to look like this:

```
Title1  January February    March
CustA   2       0           0
CustB   1       0           0
CustC   0       1           0
CustD   0       1           0
CustE   0       0           1
```

It needs to count the number of occurrences Title1 same values had and list them per month. I need to do this without using a Pivot Table and all to be done in VBA, but I have hard time figuring out the code for it.

Comment: Why can't you use a pivot table?  People here may be reluctant to spend time writing code for you when there's already a straightforward way to do what you want.

Comment: I know and I totally agree that is the way to go. But, unfortunately I have to come up with a macro code for this.

Comment: you could record a macro of the pivot table creation and use that...

Comment: You can use formulas such as Countifs(range#0,title=cust#,range#1,month=1,range#2), and loop for each month.

Comment: I can understand the need for this if your version of Excel does not support pivot tables, or if its a homework assignment.  Otherwise listen to others advising you to use the pivot table.

Comment: If you really insist on a VBA solution, then without *some* demonstrated effort at tackling this yourself, it's unlikely anyone is going to help out.

Comment: "I have to come up with a macro code instead of a pivot table" What's forcing you to do this? I'm curious if there's some restriction you haven't shared that needs to be accounted for, or if it's just a homework demand.

Comment: Tyler, I have already accepted the response from Cyril and it does help me with my project. It is Not a homework demand. The restriction is to automate the process versus using the piviot table.... Not sure why the down-vote was necessary? The question was responded....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's atypical to code for people, as no code is provided, here's an example that should get you in the right direction:

```
Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 to 12
    Cells(2,i+3).Formula="=Countifs($A$2:$A$5,$A2=""CustA"",$B$2:$B$5,Month($B2)=" & i & ")"
Next i
```

You should be able to make this hit for other rows and variables, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help with this. This would be a good starting point for me.